# Pointwise convergence of absolute value function

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Suppose that $f_1, f_2,..$ be a sequence of function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Suppose also that the sequence $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Is it true that the sequence $|f_n|$ also converges pointwise to $|f|$ ? Could you please provide a proof ?

**P/s**:
I understand that to prove the statement (if it is true), we need to prove that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a number $N > 0$ such that $||f_n(x)| - |f(x)|| < \epsilon $ for all $n > N$.

However, I don't know how to make appear the absolute value $|f_n(x)|$ as well as $|f(x)|$ from the hypothesis of pointwise convergence of $f_n$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the reverse triangle inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hint:

The reverse triangle inequality states that, if $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ then:
$$
\left||x|-|y|\right| \leq |x-y|.
$$

Can you apply this to your question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I wonder whether there is a version of this inequality in an arbitrary metric space not just the real line ?

Comment: @InTheSearchForKnowledge There is indeed! [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) talks about it. To prove this inequality, we do not use properties of the reals, but instead properties of metric/normed spaces. Therefore, it holds in all metric spaces.